# Today's inappropriate ad: fixing bunions without surgery (and probably without any doctor) on Chemistry

Tags: support, advertising, inappropriate-advertisements

Five days ago, [I wrote](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/335150/todays-inappropriate-ad-health-scam-on-travel#comment1100637_335150):

> Yeah I'm aware that "a tool to manage ad experience" is currently being developed, but as long as it's not available, I'll keep on reporting these. I'll also keep on intentionally refreshing until I get an inappropriate ad to report, because I find it to be a useful way to vent. Constructive I don't know, but useful I think so.

Today's entry being a miracle shoe fixing your bunions (*and* it's fashionable, woohoo!), I wanted to make a joke about how one shouldn't tiptoe around ads. Unfortunately, some research on bunions taught me those weren't, apparently, caused by tiptoeing.

So now I'm doubly annoyed, as I got both an inappropriate ad and a failed joke.

> [image: a shoe, and the bunion it's supposed to fix. If you're relying on this alt text to learn what a bunion is, trust me, you're better off not knowing.]

On the bright side, someone else handled the joke for me. Browsing through the totally legitimate reviews (and not complete scam [as others would pretend](https://www.trustpilot.com/review/5econds.com), right?), I learned that this wonderful *shoe* is also comfy when worn the *ears*.

> [image: review explaining that the shoe is good to wear on the ears. To each their own...]

Comment: I know this makes me a bad person, but I hope it takes a little while to fix because I enjoy your reports. (I say while I cower behind my ad blocker...)

Comment: After wearing those on my ears you no longer notice my toes ...

Comment: How to fix my feet? 50¢.  How well it fits on my ears?  Priceless.

Comment: `Yeah I'm aware that "a tool to manage ad experience" is currently being developed [...]` - [we already have that](https://github.com/gorhill/uBlock) ;)

Comment: You'll be breaking the 100k before long with these :) keep up the good work

Comment: I sincerely hope you get 10k+ from this effort.  Keep 'em coming. (+1)

Comment: @Zoethetransgirl true. It's actually enabled on my computer, though the computer itself is rarely on because it's old and slow, hence why most reports are phone screenshots. But it shouldn't have to be this way, so this regular venting helps. And if it raises some awareness about ads, their handling, etc, that can't hurt. Plus [not everyone can get an adblocker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/335622/398063), mandatory browsers in some workplaces etc. If having to see some ads means cooling down while helping others... :)

Comment: @Zoethetransgirl, I prefer [this one](https://www.eff.org/privacybadger).

Comment: @Mark I use both, in addition to the protection built into Firefox

Comment: If anyone's wondering why I didn't report anything today, it's because [I don't get ads anymore](https://chat.meta.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/7984703#7984703) for some reason. Logged out, incognito browsing, cache/cookies refresh, switched browsers, nothing except on Stack Overflow and Cross Validated which I think run on different ads providers. All this on phone; can't easily check a computer now. Maybe it's been determined that I'm [a bank of iPhones in China](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/331960/why-is-stack-overflow-trying-to-start-audio/331962#comment1083104_331962)

Comment: Are you complaining about your lack of ads? *snicker*

Comment: Can anyone help me understand what's worse about this ad than any others?  Sorry if this is a naïve question -- I am a religious user of ad blockers because irrelevant, distracting material, especially images, drive me nuts (and don't get me started on *movement* on the screen).  Are chemistry enthusiasts immune from getting bunions, and inherently uninterested in wearing sandals?

Comment: @aparente001 [this article](https://www.politico.com/magazine/story/2014/12/pharma-spam-113562) about why it's important to nuke pharma spam, for starters - the people at [Charcoal HQ](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/11540/charcoal-hq) will probably be more qualified to provide you with relevant resources

Comment: @Jenayah - Thank your for responding.  I thought this ad was for a bunion-friendly shoe, not a drug or pharmaceutical product.  (Maybe I should disclose that I am a bunion sufferer -- although I do not feel tempted to buy this shoe.)

Comment: This is now "solved" with the launch of the [Report this Ad Feature](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/345476/report-this-ad-feature)